# deepcopy YAML with top-level list comment in Python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to dump the following yaml file into multiple (different) files using ruamel.yaml:

```
C:
  f:
  # comment
  - - l1
    - l2: '5'
```

If I try to peform a `deepcopy`, the comment results in an error for the deep-copied version:

```py
import copy

from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()

conf = None
with open("input.yaml", 'r') as inf:
    conf = yaml.load(inf)
conf2 = copy.deepcopy(conf)

with open("out1.yaml", 'w') as outf:
    yaml.dump(conf, outf)

try:
    with open("out2.yaml", 'w') as outf:
        yaml.dump(conf2, outf)
    print("all good")
except AssertionError:
    raise SystemExit("Deep copy failed")
```

Is there an alternative to achieve dumping a loaded YAML with such comments into more than one file?

Comment: What is the intended goal? Do you want to copy exactly the same YAML from one file to another?

Comment: I want to be able to dump a deep-copied YAML. In my full scenario I'm performing different operations on the different deep copies before dumping them.

Comment: What is the error (full stacktrace!) for the deep-copied version? If needed to get a full stacktrace, remove the try/except.

Comment: @barny here it is: https://pastebin.com/FipNEqqg

Comment: Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 2):

This problem primarily occurs because `ruamel.yaml` development did
not start with a specification to which data structure your comment `#
comment` belongs (nor does it have one now). The fact that it is easier
to add a comment to an already created node (i.e. something in the
YAML document before the parser encounters the comment) than to add it
to a following node (which at the end of a document might not show
up).

In your example the comment could be associated with the key `f`, to
the first element of single element sequence, or to the first element
of the double item sequence. `ruamel.yaml` does try to do some rearranging and that has
resulted in the past in a single comments associated with
two consecutive nodes and that is what `merge_comments` tries to resolve by looking
at whether these comments are equal.

This is a stop-gap, but that work well enough
if you use `ruamel.yaml` for its intended purpose of load-modify-save, but the deepcopy
doesn't keep this reference, resulting in an inequality and hence the `AssertionError`

The quick and dirty solution for this is to make `merge_comments` a no-op:

```
import copy
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()

conf = None
with open("input.yaml", 'r') as inf:
    conf = yaml.load(inf)
conf2 = copy.deepcopy(conf)

with open("out1.yaml", 'w') as outf:
    yaml.dump(conf, outf)

yaml.representer.merge_comments = lambda x, y: None

try:
    with open("out2.yaml", 'w') as outf:
        yaml.dump(conf2, outf)
    print("all good")
except AssertionError:
    raise SystemExit("Deep copy failed")
```

which gives:

```
all good
```

With the content of `out1.yaml`:

```
C:
  f:
  # comment
  - - l1
    - l2: '5'
```

and of `out2.yaml`:

```
C:
  f:
  # comment
  - - l1
    - l2: '5'
```

This problem is "enhanced" as the `__deepcopy__` for the
representation of the list and mapping, does a deepcopy of the
attributes that hold comment, flow, format, anchor, etc. information
without following the advice in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html):

> If the **deepcopy**() implementation needs to make a deep copy of a
>     component, it should call the deepcopy() function with the component
>     as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.

But changing that doesn't fix the problem, a more structural solution
would be to have a non-ambiguous definition of what a comment will apply to and
do away with `merge_comments`. That should
include splitting of multi-line comments as in:

```
# this documents has some non-trivial
# comment lines

# first item follows
- 42
# end of first item

# second item follows
- 196
# end of second item

# final comment of the document
```

Currently the above will load with three (mult-line) comments, but IMO
would be more appropriate to interpret that as being six comments. The
major task being the definition of splitting such comments without interpreting the meaning of the comment, only using empty lines.

Additionally the indent level of a comment might be taken into account for node-assignment.